# Example for parsing (X)Html with libxml2 in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, html-parsing, libxml2

Recently I started to play around with the libxml2 lib within an iOS iPhone project. I read some useful links, like:

http://laurentparenteau.com/blog/2009/12/parsing-xhtml-in-c-a-libxml2-tutorial/

and some very nice post here:

http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/libxml2_push_parsing

I managed to retrieve remote html (with ASIHTTPRequest) and successfully get the data (NSData) on the 'didReceiveData' event pushed to a wrapper class containing a parser created with **htmlCreatePushParserCtxt** (SAX style). I get nicely the startDocument
and endDocument callbacks. In the 'startElement' and 'characters' callbacks,  I print the ' localname' paramater (**const xmlChar**). In the console I see that it finds 'html', then 'body', then some 'p' tag, but then I get lots of unrecognizable characters (sometimese it looks even like Chinese..)...

Anyway, before getting into to much code details, I want to ask if anyone has a working example of parsing (x)html with libxml2 in an objective-c based projet? I tried googling for more then the 2 mentioned links, but until now no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose `AQXMLParser` by alan quartemain : http://blog.alanquatermain.me/2013/01/09/using-aqxmlparser-and-friends/

it is a thin wrapper aroung libxml2 and a lot more performat than NSXMLParser.

set `HTMLMode` property to yes so it uses libxml in html mode.. (I used it many times and it does quite well even with non-valid html)

Answer (score -3):

Why would you want to use `libxml2` over Apple's built-in `NSXMLParser` class?  If you are making an application for iOS, it makes more sense to use a Foundation class for this than a C library.  You can access the documentation for NSXMLParser [on Apple's website](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you don't want to use NSXMLParser directly, you could try parsing XML with [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which has an easy-to-use `- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSUInteger)mask error:(NSError **)error` method for parsing XML data.  You can even use the `NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML` option for the init method to read HTML data as XHTML.

Comment: Well the answer for that can be found in the 4th paragraph in the post of the link I mentioned: http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/libxml2_push_parsing

Comment: the NSXMLParser has a high memory footprint AND more importantly: doesnt like html.

Comment: NSXMLDocument isnt available on ios, KissXML provides a drop in replacement